# Angular can't get requests from Spring API using Azure Authentication

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

For a project I have a Back-end using Spring-boot and a front-end using angular. The communication works perfect. Since I added Azure authentication it stopped working. When I try to access the API from angular all the requests return no status code and just an error.

I did a few things trying to fix the bug:

1. The response headers gave as "location" the authentication API. I found out that Angular didn't send the cookies with the requests. I fixed this and now the response header doesn't return the login API as location. But I still get errors on all my request to the api.
2. I have also made sure that the back-end allows CORS from all senders. This did not fix the problem either.

So I have no idea what could be causing the request to fail. I copied the exact request with the same headers in postman and there it works perfect. I can also acces the API in the same browser as where i'm using Angular with the same cookie.

Any suggestions on what could be wrong are welcome!

Thank you!

I have added a screenshot of one of the requests that Angular sends to the back-end.

[image]

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: My requests in chrome network tab just show "(failed)net::ERR_FAILED". I have no idea what this means. No status code or anything...

Comment: your request url is showing of a localhost server, are you sure your backend is up?

Comment: Yes, the back-end is hosted on localhost:8080 and the front-end on localhost:4200.

Comment: you are sure in your devtools, in network tab you have not checked offline checkbox accidentally?

Comment: hey did you check?

Comment: Yes I did, offline was not checked. I tried this in firefox and firefox gave way more information about the error than google chrome. There were some errors about cors.
I fixed it by adding .allowCredentials(true); in the back-end and disable csrf().

Thank you for the support!